# Counting the number of strings with vowels in a list of list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to count the number of strings with vowels in them given a list of list of strings. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def count_vowels(list):
    """ (list of list of str) -> int

    Return the number of vowel-inclusive strings in a list of list of str.

    >>> list = [['X', 'OW1'], ['Z', 'AH1', 'R']]
    >>> count_vowels(list)
    2
    """

    for sublist in list:
        num_vowels = 0
        for item in sublist:
            if item in "aeiouAEIOU":
                num_vowels += 1
    return num_vowels
```

Comment: So what is going wrong? What output are you getting and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Don't use `list` as an argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm getting 0 when I should be getting 2.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Changing the name of `list` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Ingrid what Malik means is that you shouldn't use the name of built-in types, functions, or modules as variable names - `list`, `dict`, `string`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `item` is a complete string. `AH1` is not going to be found in `"aeiouAEIOU"` as there is no such substring in the vowel string.

You are also resetting the `num_vowels` total per sublist, so you'll only get the total for the last element by the time you return the value.

You could loop over each of the vowels and test those individually:

```
def count_vowels(lst):
    num_vowels = 0
    for sublist in lst:
        for item in sublist:
            for vowel in "aeiouAEIOU":
                if vowel in item:
                    num_vowels += 1
                    break
    return num_vowels
```

I used the name `lst` instead of `list` to not mask the built-in type. The `break` ends the `for vowel` loop when you have determined that there is indeed at least one vowel in the item.

This isn't all that efficient. You can reduce the number of tests by lowercasing the item and testing only for lowercase vowels:

```
def count_vowels(lst):
    num_vowels = 0
    for sublist in lst:
        for item in sublist:
            item = item.lower()
            for vowel in "aeiou":
                if vowel in item:
                    num_vowels += 1
                    break
    return num_vowels
```

You could use set intersections to find if there is an intersection with the vowels set:

```
def count_vowels(lst):
    num_vowels = 0
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    for sublist in lst:
        for item in sublist:
            if vowel.intersection(item.lower())
                num_vowels += 1
    return num_vowels
```

or use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression; it'll do the same thing as the `for` loop with a `break`; it exits early when a matching vowel has been found:

```
def count_vowels(lst):
    num_vowels = 0
    for sublist in lst:
        for item in sublist:
            item = item.lower()
            if any(vowel in item for vowel in "aeiou")
                num_vowels += 1
    return num_vowels
```

If you use the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) you can collapse counting the words into

```
def count_vowels(lst):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    return sum(1 
        for sublist in lst 
        for item in sublist
        if vowel.intersection(item.lower()))
```

Comment: Ey! Marty, `list` as variable!!

Comment: @BhargavRao: poko poko, all good things take time.

Comment: This function can be simplified to two lines with the `any` and `sum` functions.

Comment: @MartjinPieters Thanks very much. This helped a lot. I'm not yet familiar with the `any` and `sum` functions but nice to know they're out there!

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: yes, but that doesn't help a newcomer understand *why their attempt failed*.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find if a word has a vowel by doing `s in "aeiouAEIOU"`, which isn't the same as "the string has a vowel". You could do this:

```
if any(c in item for c in "aeiouAEIOU"):
  num_vowels += 1
```

Or you could do this:

```
if len(set(item) & set("aeiouAEIOU")) > 0: #this may be faster if you precompute set("aeiouAEIOU")
  num_vowels += 1
```

Or if you want to use regex:

```
r = re.compile("[aeiouAEIOU]") #compute this one out of your loop
if r.search(item):
  num_vowels += 1
```

All will work, up to you to find which one is faster.

Comment: `len(...) > 0` can be removed altogether; an empty set is false in a boolean context.

Comment: True but the OP is already having trouble with a simple program, so I think this extra verbosity is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just unpack the list of lists into a single list then check for vowels:

```
def count_vowels(data):
    data = itertools.chain.from_iterable(data) # data is first arg
    return sum(1 for i in data if any(j in i for j in 'aeiouAEIOU'))
```

In the first line, the nested list is made to a single list. The second line checks for any vowels with in each item returning the sum of the items that tested positive in the vowel check with the use of the `sum` and `any` built-in methods.